# ambiguous use of method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

My build completes successfully. Then after some time this error pops up:

> "Ambiguous use of 'addObjectsDidChangeNotificationObserver(handler:)'"

What I do not understand is why this happens because the `addObjectsDidChangeNotificationObserver` method is only declared once in the project and the second occurence shown by Xcode is the use of the method itself.

[image: Found candidate 1]

[image: Error location]

Here is the code where the error is shown and which Xcode also shows me as first candidate:

```
public init?(object: Managed, changeHandler: @escaping (ChangeType) -> ()) {
    guard let moc = object.managedObjectContext else { return nil }

    objectHasBeenDeleted = !type(of: object).defaultPredicate.evaluate(with: object)

    token = moc.addObjectsDidChangeNotificationObserver(handler: {
        [unowned self] note in
        guard let changeType = self.changeType(of: object, in: note) else { return }
        self.objectHasBeenDeleted = changeType == .delete
        changeHandler(changeType)
    })
}
```

and the implementation of `addObjectsDidChangeNotificationObserver()`, which Xcode shows me as second candidate:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {
    public func addObjectsDidChangeNotificationObserver(handler: @escaping (ObjectsDidChangeNotification) -> ()) -> NSObjectProtocol {
        let nc = NotificationCenter.default
        return nc.addObserver(forName: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: self, queue: nil) { note in
            let wrappedNote = ObjectsDidChangeNotification(note: note)
            handler(wrappedNote)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question by posting actual code as text, not as pictures. Code in pictures can't be referenced or searched.

Comment: There's some third party library involved. This notification is not part of the Core Data framework

Comment: No, i haven't used any third party library

Comment: No? What's about [that one](https://github.com/objcio/core-data/tree/master/SharedCode)?

Comment: I used the "Core Data" book by Florian Kugler, but didn't import the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to be solved now.

Apparently, I messed up with the access modifiers, but good to know that something like that can cause an ambiguous error